# Worklight application login in multiple devices with same user at same time

Tags: authentication, ibm-mobilefirst

I have an Application developed using worklight. My problem is i am able login into app at same time in multiple devices. Is there any way to avoid this in worklight.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can record all logins into a database table and check for the username if it is exists in the table. if exists it means that the same username is logged in to system. in the table, you can record username, login date, maybe ip address and a bit column for logout. On logout you should update the row by setting the bit column to true. I am using this logic on my projects to avoid multiple login with the same user.

Comment: Thanks for Response. Can we handle same thing in worklight side

Comment: yes you can. you should check the server for is user already logged in with isUserAuthenticated("username") method. [Check this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20118478/worklight-how-to-check-if-a-client-is-already-logged-in-then-pass-the-login-s)